# Nuxt 3 sending formData using routeRules & useFetch()

Tags: nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3, nitro

I use routeRules to proxy requests to backend:

```
  routeRules: {
    '/api/**': {
      proxy: process.env.BASE_URL
        ? `${process.env.BASE_URL}/**`
        : 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/**',
    }
  },
```

Request which should be sent to backend:

```
const { data, pending, error, refresh } = await useServerAPI(
  '/image/upload',
  {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData,
    credentials: 'include',
  }
)
```

And i receive error:
`[nuxt] [request error] [unhandled] [500] fetch failed`.
If i set body with no formData with file request works as expected (returns Unprocessable entity with NestJS Multer plugin).

`useServerAPI.ts` composable code:

```
import { useFetch } from '#app'
type useFetchType = typeof useFetch
export const useServerAPI: useFetchType = (path, options = {}) => {
  const config = useRuntimeConfig()

  options.baseURL = config.public.baseURL as string
  return useFetch(path, options)
}
```